# how to unlock a file from the deleted workspace in TFS

Tags: tfs

After performing merge, deleted the workspace before doing deleting forgot undo the changes. Created a new workspace and when merged the files in newworkspace. 
Getting an error: item is already locked in the workspace.

So how to unlock the files from already deleted workspace.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have TFS instance to test it, but first I would try to undo all changes in the workspace you deleted, using tf undo (https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/c72skhw4.aspx) you are able to specify there workspace name.
You can also try using tfs sidekick to do similar thing (http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/) but I always used just tf.exe
Good luck!